# Share extension only with specific URL

Tags: ios, predicate, ios-extensions

Is there a way to filter Share extension to show only when, for example, the URL domain is a specific one?

For example, I want to show my app extension only when the user is sharing a google link:

`http://www.google.com/?someQuery`

If I'm filtering to get URLs, a code like below would be sufficient:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
).@count == 1
```

In this case the predicate access the `$attachment`'s `registeredTypeIdentifiers` property and evaluate it. I want to be able to match a REGEX against the value inside the `$attachment`, something like this:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" AND
        ANY $attachment.value MATCHES "^http\:\/\/www\.google\.com\/"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
).@count == 1
```

... so my extension would be invisible when my application don't support the URL shared by the host app.

**PS:** Note that the URL domain used is only an example. The real one, of course, have a meaning to be used like this.

Comment: ever found any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: Please do share the solution if you find anything on this.

Comment: We did not have a solution at the time (4 yrs ago) , so we changed the interface to accept any URL shared, and respond with an alert message in case of the URL be incompatible with the app.